# MySQL Database Maintenance with MyISAM and InnoDB tables

Tags: mysql, database

I am new to MySQL and I am looking for some database maintenance tips.

I have a older website that has a MySQL database version 5.1.29 with a mix of MyISAM and InnoDB tables.  99% of the tables are MyISAM and two of them are InnoDB.

I found this nice article [MySQL Maintenance Tasks for InnoDB with MySQL 5.1](http://www.laurencegellert.com/2011/07/mysql-maintenance-tasks-for-innodb-with-mysql-5-1/) that describes some maintenance tasks for InnoDB.

What do you suggest for database maintenance in my environment?

Comment: My advice...if the DB is small, and it's working perfect, don't touch it

Comment: Shouldn't this go to Database Administrators site: http://dba.stackexchange.com/?as=1?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your tables are used. Those that are appended to and updated are usually about as optimal as they can get. Those where you add and remove a large number of records can become more inefficient, but an `OPTIMIZE TABLE` on these will tighten them up.

Although the "If it's not broke don't fix it" rule applies here, it's worth converting your MyISAM tables to InnoDB if you can do this on a test instance and no problems arise. MyISAM tables have a number of deficiencies, but the primary one is they're not journaled and can become corrupted beyond repair if you suffer a server crash at an unfortunate time.

The best maintenance you can do on MySQL is by keeping the version up-to-date. 5.1 is a number of versions behind, and moving to 5.5 would provide significant performance benefits.